# This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.ts(2745)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, styled-components

I am writing a component `Text` that accepts `size` prop based on which a Styled component could be returned. I am using the polymorphic `as` prop from Styled Components to do so. However, when TypeScript keeps throwing these errors. I am also using transient props to prevent passing the props intended for StyledText to the ReactNode.

For `<StyledText>` component

```
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.ts(2745)
```

And for `as` prop in Styled Components

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, "color" | "slot" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & StyledTextProps, "color" | ... 259 more ... | "$align"> & Partial<...>, "color" | ... 259 more ... | "$align"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

I have created a simplified example in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-leftpad-2nbde?file=/src/Text.tsx)

Any pointers on what am I doing wrong or recommended reading is highly appreciated.

Also pasting the code below:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export interface TextProps {
  color?: "primary" | "secondary" | "primaryText" | "secondaryText" | "error";
  size?: "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "overline";
  weight?: "normal" | "bold" | "bolder" | "lighter" | "number";
  display?: "inline" | "block" | "inherit";
  align?: "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify" | "initial" | "inherit";
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

interface StyledTextProps {
  $color?: TextProps["color"];
  $size?: TextProps["size"];
  $weight?: TextProps["weight"];
  $display?: TextProps["display"];
  $align?: TextProps["align"];
}

const StyledText = styled.span<StyledTextProps>`
  font-family: var(--default-font-family);
  margin: 0;
  display: ${(props) => (props.$display ? props.$display : `inherit`)};
  text-align: ${(props) => (props.$align ? props.$align : `inherit`)};
  font-weight: ${(props) => (props.$weight ? props.$weight : `normal`)};
`;

const sizeToHeading: Record<string, string> = {
  "0": "p",
  "1": "h1",
  "2": "h2",
  "3": "h3",
  "4": "h4",
  "5": "h5",
  "6": "h6"
};

export const Text = React.forwardRef<HTMLSpanElement, TextProps>(
  ({ ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <StyledText
          ref={ref}
          $size={props.size || "6"}
          as={props.size ? sizeToHeading[props.size] : "p"}
        >
          {props.children}
        </StyledText>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Please see my update, no need to add `as` type to `StyledTextProps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

NO NEED to add `as` type to `StyledTextProps`, changing `sizeToHeading` type will do the trick

updated codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-bell-66hvq?file=/src/Text.tsx:964-1115

```
const sizeToHeading: Record<string, React.ElementType> = { // use ElementType here
  "0": "p",
  "1": "h1",
  "2": "h2",
  "3": "h3",
  "4": "h4",
  "5": "h5",
  "6": "h6"
};
```

---

**OLD**

Adding the `as` type should be able to get rid of the type error.

Here is the codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-brown-9x8xe?file=/src/Text.tsx

```
interface StyledTextProps {
  $color?: TextProps["color"];
  $size?: TextProps["size"];
  $weight?: TextProps["weight"];
  $display?: TextProps["display"];
  $align?: TextProps["align"];
  as?: React.ElementType; // mark `as` as react element type which are fundamental html tags
}

const sizeToHeading: Record<string, React.ElementType> = { // use ElementType here as well
  "0": "p",
  "1": "h1",
  "2": "h2",
  "3": "h3",
  "4": "h4",
  "5": "h5",
  "6": "h6"
};
```

Comment: Do you know the reasoning behind this? Although the functionality was working even previously, TS was giving those nasty errors with squiggly lines. Now they are resolved but I don't fully understand why it worked. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Because the `as` only accepts `ElementType`. although `p`, `h1` are `ElementType` but if you say it is a `string` instead of `ElementType`, typescript will treat them as incompatible even they look the same to us

Comment: So, giving back the correct type, `as` can recognise `p` is not a simple string but  one of the members in ElementType . I admit typescript error is hard to guess what the meaning behind is .... sometime needs to read though the `index.d.ts` to find the right type like this one.

Comment: yeah..I got it. Thanks for the reply!